# Domino Document to MS Word

Tags: ms-word, xpages, lotus-domino

I need to export a Domino document with RTF (images, tables, etc) to MS.Word in background mode or via Web. I have tried with POI4Xpages but I don't know how to export it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your POI document to an output stream. This could be a fileOutputStream or the response. When using the response you need to set the header to reflect the file type. Check for XAgent for a sample how to do that. See: https://www.wissel.net/blog/2008/12/xagents-web-agents-xpages-style.html